# Ajax json get data from domain

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am working on phonegap and trying to get list of user using ajax 
call but my function is returning nothing on mobile its working
fine in browser

here is the function and url data is in xml format

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://my_server_url/user/selectuser",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("Success:"+data.detail[0].Username);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("Error:"+data);
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert( "page not found" );
        }
    }
}); 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: your server allows cross domain requests?

Comment: How does the function selectuser look like? What is it returning?

Comment: @Fawzan: JSONP is unaffected by CORS.

Comment: It works in browser and i am getting data but not in phonegap app.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, its returning xml format data like `{"message":"Success","detail":[{"Usr_Id":"1","Username":"first"},{"Usr_Id":"2","Username":"second"}]}`

Comment: Can you pull up the resource with a regular Chrome/Mobile Safari tab? If not, is there anything special about your setup (e.g. is your Hosts file modified, is the server behind a firewall or on a different network)? Try debugging the app in a Safari/Chrome debugger over USB.

Comment: Actually, i am creating apk and test it to the mobile phone so not know how to debug this in mobile chrome, if i set alert in the beginning of function i get it but then nothing happens with success, error or 404

Comment: As long as you aren't building the production APK, you usually can still debug over USB. It depends on your setup, but I've never had a problem debugging until packaging the final product (at which point, the debug hooks are removed and the app should be invisible to Chrome/Safari).

Comment: It seems like you're returning json and not jsonp from you're function? try changing the datatype to json.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, jQuery abstracts away the json/jsonp distinction. It shouldn't make a difference. And assuming the poster is not mistaken, the code works in a browser.

Comment: can you show us an EXACT result of "`http://my_server_url/user/selectuser?callback=gavriel`"? Also have you tried to use `jsonpCallback: "function_name"` ?

Comment: @Andrew - maybe so, but it doesn't seem right to define the incorrect datatype for future usage. It's not sure that jQuery always will do those distrinctions.

Comment: Can you show us the code of selectuser-function ?

Comment: working fine in browser is irrelevant if the page is on same domain as api is but isn't serving jsonp as requested

Comment: My code isnt on same domain as well jsonp was not returning anything while json atleast jump into function and now i m getting error function and status code 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general steps I go through for checking problems like this on mobile are:

1. The simplest thing you can do is try pulling up the resource via a regular browser window on your phone and see what's different. Just type in the URL and see what happens. If you can't pull it down on a generic Chrome / Mobile Safari tab, the error may help you figure out what the problem is. If you can pull it down, the problem likely resides in your code (a typo in the URL perhaps). This won't work if you aren't doing a `GET` request, but it may at least help you figure out if your phone can reach your server.
2. Connect your device to your PC on USB and observe the request in a Safari/Chrome debugger's Network tab. You should probably be doing this all the time anyway, but it always seems to be my step #2.
3. Set one breakpoint before your request is sent, another in the success handler and a third in the error handler. The request may be successful, but an error immediately after the response could be stopping your program. Or maybe the response text is not what you were expecting (a web page rather than a JSON stream.)
4. If you are doing a non-`GET` request (like you are here), you can try running your own AJAX request directly in the debugger console. If you duplicate the request exactly, it shouldn't give you any more information than watching the regular request in the network tab, but it does allow you to modify the request multiple times without recompiling your app. It can be a huge time-saver.

If your phone can't reach the resource at all (#1) then maybe you have a specialized local environment that your phone doesn't share. For example, you might be calling `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, which your phone will never reach (because these IP addresses have a special meaning on most networks and basically means 'me' or 'this computer'). Or maybe you're calling out to something like `192.168.xxx.xxx` or `10.xxx.xxx.xxx`, which your phone can't reach because it isn't on that private network (e.g if you are not on the same wifi). In this case, you have two options:

1. figure out how to expose those resources to outside requests, or
2. get your phone into your network environment. In extreme cases, I've actually had to build my own DNS server, change my phone's networks settings to use that, and redirect requests going to specific domain names.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, i found that my url is an IP address and not a domain name, so may be it is not accessible by mobile device, so can you please tell me how to get domain name from ip address ?

Comment: Ah, first of all, '192.168.x.x', '10.0.x.x', '127.0.0.1' and 'localhost' all have a special meaning. The first two are 'local network'. The second two are 'this PC'. 
Besides this, Tthe problem isn't IP addresses or domain names in this case. The problem is network connection. If you can't get a response from the IP address, you need to figure out how to get your phone onto the same network as your dev machine. If you are hosting everything on your PC, try setting up your PC as a hotspot and connect to it with your phone. Or connect the phone to your local Wifi.

Comment: Another possibility is that your PC is blocking external HTTP requests. You should tread carefully (never loosen your computer's security without a very good reason), but you would need to modify your firewall to allow requests on port 80 (or whatever port your server is listening on).

Answer (score 0):

With Phonegap version "Cli-5.2.0", whitelist plugin need to be use to successfully make ajax call on Android. Add below mentioned line in config.xml to use whitelist plugin with Phonegap cloud build.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Check https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for whitelist plugin description

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Krunal, but in the cordova cli this plugin in installed by default and origin and intent added default to its config file so no need to add this into app.

Comment: Can you verify whether "cordova-plugin-whitelist" plugin is added successfully? I had face same issue for Android while migrating our app from phonegap 3.x to Phonegap cli-5.2. After adding above config, issue was fixed. Just verify once that plugin is added successfully to your app and all above config lines are present in config.xml.

Comment: One more thing, are you using local build or phonegap cloud build?

Comment: I am using local build and yes that plugin and config lines are present in config.xml file

Comment: I hope you had added local plugin as "phonegap plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git". If you had added that local plugin and still not working then I would suggest you to try once using Phonegap cloud build and check whether it build successfully on that or not